# how to install the dotnet driver for neo4j on windows 10 using powershell package manager

Tags: neo4j

My goal is to install the neo4j dotnet driver so I can script it from Excel VBA.  Hence I am using the windows powershell install package command as shown below.

PS:>    Install-Package Neo4j.Driver-1.2.1

and I got the following error  message:

```
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Neo4j.Driver-1.2.1'. Try
Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Neo4j.Driver-1.2.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

I think my problem is that my powershell environment is not configured to find packages using nuget.  This is all pretty new to me so any help is appreciated.
Here is my current setup:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-packagesource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
nuget.org                        NuGet            False      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    False      https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> find-packageprovider

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
nuget                          2.8.5.208        https://onege... NuGet provider for the OneGet meta-package manager
psl                            1.0.0.210        https://onege... psl provider for the OneGet meta-package manager
chocolatey                     2.8.5.130        https://onege... ChocolateyPrototype provider for the OneGet meta-pa...
DockerMsftProvider             1.0.0.1          PSGallery        PowerShell module with commands for discovering, in...
PowerShellGet                  1.1.3.2          PSGallery        PowerShell module with commands for discovering, in...
ContainerImage                 0.6.4.0          PSGallery        This is a PackageManagement provider module which h...
GistProvider                   0.6              PSGallery        Gist-as-a-Package - PackageManagement  PowerShell P...
GitHubProvider                 0.5              PSGallery        GitHub-as-a-Package - PackageManagement PowerShell ...
NanoServerPackage              1.0.1.0          PSGallery        A PackageManagement provider to  Discover, Save and...
ChocolateyGet                  1.0.0.1          PSGallery        An PowerShell OneGet provider that discovers packag...
TSDProvider                    0.2              PSGallery        PowerShell PackageManager provider to search & inst...
DockerMsftProviderInsider      1.0.0.2          PSGallery        PowerShell module with commands for discovering, in...
OfficeProvider                 1.0.0.1          PSGallery        OfficeProvider allows users to install Microsoft Of...
GitLabProvider                 1.3.4            PSGallery        GitLab PackageManagement provider
MyAlbum                        0.1.2            PSGallery        MyAlbum provider discovers the photos in your remot...
WSAProvider                    1.0.0.4          PSGallery        Provider to Discover, Install and inventory windows...
0install                       2.13.6           PSGallery        Zero Install is a decentralized cross-platform soft...
DockerProvider                 0.0.0.3          PSGallery        PowerShell module with commands for discovering, in...
AppxGet                        0.1.0.1          PSGallery        Powershell Package Management (OneGet) Provider for...

When I do a find-package command I only see packages from the PSGallery source event though NuGet is listed as one of my package sources.  Here is a partial output from find-package.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> find-package

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
AzureRM.profile                3.4.0            PSGallery        Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Profile credential
Azure.Storage                  3.4.0            PSGallery        Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Storage service cm

Answer (score 1):

Try installing without version specified:

```
PM> Install-Package Neo4j.Driver
```

You'll get the latest version (currently 1.4.1).

**EDIT** - I did some digging. Looks like there's a .net version dependency, and v1.2.1 doesn't appear to work with .net 4.5.2. I just changed a local test project to 4.6.1, and now the v1.2.1 of the driver installs fine. So, I'd suggest checking your .net version (or simply stick with the latest Neo4j driver version).

Also: The way you're specifying the package, that doesn't look correct. Here's how to specify the version:

```
PM> Install-Package Neo4j.Driver -version 1.2.1
```

Comment: David - thanks.  I added additional info to my original post.  my command looks wrong because I'm using the powershell package manager commands, not the package manager inside visual studio.